# Reg: goldengate extract process need to write for scn for abend state

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-golden-gate

any sample  script for sending  SCN DETAILS AND DB TIMESTAMP when EXTRACT IS ABENDED --- EXTRACT for source DB

is there any suggestions

Comment: can we add this: 
when extract abended  check the archive log sequence number from logdump

with that sequence number check NEXT_CHANGE# from v$archivedlog

Answer (score 0):

If you do "info <extract_name>, showch", it will show you the recovery checkpoint and current checkpoint for the redo log reading position.  Those output has SCN and timestamp info in it.  The recovery checkpoint tracks the oldest open transaction Extract is reading from.  The current checkpoint tracks the last committed transaction's SCN Extract just finished processing before stop.